# How to client/server game using Google App Engine (Looking for tutorial.)

Tags: client-server, google-app-engine

(NOTE: This is a duplicate of [a question I asked on SO,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347132/how-to-client-server-game-using-google-app-engine) having temporarily forgotten about GameDev <hang head in shame>.  When one is answered, I will link it back to the other.)

I'm trying to do my first client/server game using Google Apps Engine as my back end (specification requirement.) I've done the tutorials (Java), but that all seems highly browser-centric.

Basically, I'd like my (mobile, not that it matters) app to:

- Allow the user to create a game-account (NOT their Google account!)
- Log-in with that account.
- Press the "MARCO" button to send an account-identified request to the server.
- Get a "POLO" response from the server.

  - As data (like a JSON object, XML-DOM or similar), not as a web-page.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial/sample project/detailed reading to help me achieve that? I'm pretty sure that, once I get that working, I can do all the rest of it -- but I'm having the "stuck at the starting gate" problem, not being able to work up basic account-login, and non-HTML data exchange.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the server side going to be written in Java or Python? Will a simple database on the server suffice or do you need to perform much game logic?

Comment: @Alex: I'm writing in Java.  There will be both simple database and some game logic, although I'm not sure why that matters for my question.  The part where I'm getting stuck is in the setting-up of user-authentication.  The Marco/Polo example was just a trivial game-data exchange, but the key part I'm having trouble with is the user authentication stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that wasn't clicking for me -- and, as I suspected, was very very simple -- was that it's just a matter of implementing the doPost() (or doGet(), but I use POST) routine, and write back to the responder.

There were also some bits that I didn't follow quite correctly the first time about setting-up the responder class-names and URLs, in the web.xml file (in the war folder.)

Once I got that (web.xml) set up correctly, then the doPost() routine was simply something along the lines of:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws IOException {
    String reqTypeStr = req.getParameter("reqType");
    if (reqTypeStr.equalsIgnoreCase("marco")
        resp.getWriter().println("Polo!");
    else
            resp.getWriter().println("huh?");
}
```

There are myriad other details but those were the two that hung me up the most.  Once I broke that simple barrier, everything else flowed together very quickly.

Comment: NOTE: This *still* doesn't point me at a decent tutorial/walkthrough, which is what I originally asked so, if someone points me to a brilliant one of those, I'll mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have a working example of a client/server game built on App Engine. You can [fork it on GitHub](http://github.com/richtaur/Valadria) and [try the live demo](http://playvaladria.appspot.com/).

I haven't written about it or anything yet, but the code is relatively well commented. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

For something that simple I would recommend using python(and in general the python GAE experience is quite good.)

I am pretty sure that for what you want to do the simple app engine tutorial and documentation woud be enough. You want to create an application that has 3 controllers( check credentials, create credentials and answer marco-polo).

There are a bunch of open source examples of python code for the app engine in github, and a lot of documentation on the official site, i would say go try it out and if you run into a wall ask a specific question =D

Hope that helps!

Comment: Learning a new language (python) isn't in the client-spec; I know Java, and am on time constraint.  The object hierarchy should all be similar, no?

I understand that what I'm asking is very-very-simple.  But I've done the tutorials, and it's just not clicking for me.  Also, the tutorials don't show quite what I'm asking, and I can't quite figure out how to convert to "not-Google-account"s.